# Using Object.create() to develop a prototype chain

Tags: javascript

I have seen people writing this when want to extend another class:

```
Test2.prototype = Object.create( Test1.prototype );
```

But I did this too:

```
Test2.prototype = Test1.prototype;
```

And works (at least in the following example):

```
var Teste1 = function() 
{
    this.value = 'Teste1';
}
Teste1.prototype = {
    value:'no-class',
    print:function()
    {
        console.log( this.value );
    }
}

var Teste2 = function()
{
    Teste1.apply( this );
}
Teste2.prototype = Teste1.prototype;

var t = new Teste2();
t.print();
```

The console prints `Teste1`, which means Teste1 constructor was called. The real questions are:

Why do we need use `Object.create` when extending classes in javascript?
Will I get a problem with this idea of code in the future on the project?

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference between

```
Test2.prototype = Object.create( Test1.prototype );
```

and

```
Test2.prototype = Test1.prototype;
```

is that in the first example, you're creating a *new* object that uses `Test1.prototype` as its prototype. In the second example, you're just pointing the `Test2.prototype` property at the **same object** that `Test1.prototype` points to.

This has important ramifications, specifically that if you add properties via your `Test2.prototype` reference:

```
Test2.prototype.newProperty = 42;
```

...with the first example you don't end up changing the object `Test1.prototype` points to, but in the second example, you do, because both `Test2.prototype` and `Test1.prototype` are pointing to the **same** object.